# For loop with certain items in array requiring different classes for a certain period of days

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which display 24 offers in an advent calendar. On the current day the offer is available, past day offers are given the expired class and future day offers are disabled.

However there are some days where the offers area available for more than 1 day, could be 7, 3 etc.

So my question is how do I make an except for certain days?

My thinking is that i need to do if `i[7]` in the `else if` statement in the `item` div...

`else if ($today[mday] > $i ) { echo "expired"; }`

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) { ?>
<a href="offer.php?day=<?php echo $i; ?><? echo '&dealership='. $dealership; ?>" class="item <? if ($today[mday] == $i ) { echo " current yellow"; } else if ($today[mday] < $i+1 ) { echo "disabled gift"; } else if ($today[mday] > $i ) { echo "expired"; } ?>">
    <div class="offer">
        <h2>Day <?php echo $i; ?>.</h2>
        <span class="unavailable">No Longer Available</span>
        <p><? echo call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'CAL_OFFER'); ?></p>
        <? echo $termsLink; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="offer-img">
        <img src="img/day<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg">
    </div>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `for ($i = date("d"); ... ) { ... }` may be what you are looking for, it gets the current day and *plonks* it into `$i`, i.e. Today would make `$i = 02`

Comment: the problem with that is that it doesn't include past days, so day1 will not be included in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 24 offers and want to make some offers available more than one day, create an array with the number of days the offer is valid:

```
$offer = array( 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 7 ... );

$today = intval( date( 'j' ) );

for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) {
    if ( $today >= $i && $today < $i+$offer[$i-1] )
        // Current offer
    else if ( $today > $i )
        // Expired
    else
        // Disabled
}
```

**UPDATED** Added $today and fixed an issue with the first if statement

Comment: Thank you that worked :). I know this is a separate question but if i wanted to manually set $today as day 7 just to test how would i do that?

Comment: LOL! Try changing `$today = intval( date( 'j' ) );` to `$today = 7;`

Comment: Thanks, i just replaced 'j' for a number :)

Comment: if i start a new question can you help or shall i post here?

Comment: Start a new question! If I am available, I will see if I can help!

Comment: it's ok i just figured it out, i might post it anyway tomorrow and see if you have a different answer, thanks for your help, greatly appreciated :)